# Angular 2 router navigate where param value is 1

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm having a really strange issue where if I attempt to use the router's `navigate` method and one of my param values is equal to `1` the parameter is left blank in the url.

`this._router.parent.navigate([route, { a:2, b:3, c:1 }]);`

produces a url like

`http://localhost:9000/#?a=2&b=3&c`

I have confirmed that issue occurs even if I convert the number to string, i.e.

`this._router.parent.navigate([route, { a:2, b:3, c:'1' }]);`

For the sake of completeness, my `RouteConfig` looks like so

```
@RouteConfig([
    new Route({ path: '/', component: ShellComponent, name: 'Browse' })
])
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: Managed to get a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bYXXDM55ZELKwOsXds0U?p=preview) up and running - it will need to be opened in a separate window in order to update the url. Click the square blue button in the top right of the preview window

**EDIT 2**: As pointed out below this is a [known bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5346) in Angular 2.

Comment: Please provide some working code where the issue can be observed like a jsfiddle or a plunk. This helps in solving problems

Comment: @Jigar I've tried building one but can't get router to update the Url on plunkr

Comment: You were already told that this is a [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5346), so you should update the question to mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem on my side with version beta0... It seems to be a bug in Angular2 and to be linked to the name of the parameter and not to their number.

As a workaround, you could perhaps use it as a path parameter: `path: '/:c'`:

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/:c', component: ShellComponent, name: 'Browse'}
])
```

This works for me...

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure this will work for me as the parameter is optional and Angular throws an error if the parameter is not included. I would also end up with a url structured like `localhost/1`, as opposed to `localhost/?param=1`